# "No visible interface" for existing method

Tags: ios

This is my .h file:

```
@interface test1ViewController : UIViewController{}

    -(void)function1:(NSString *)param1:(NSString *)param2 ;
@end
```

Here is my .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self function1:@"333" param2:@"sadfas"];
}


-(void)function1:(NSString *)param1:(NSString *)param2 { }
```

This line of code gives me an error, stating: **no visible @interface .... declares the selector 'function1:param2**:

`[self function1:@"333" param2:@"sadfas"    ];`

I tried to modify this a bit, but could not get it to work. How do I fix this

Comment: That doesn't look like a correct multiple-parameter method definition or declaration. (Extrapolating from Smalltalk, it should be something like `- (void) function1: (NSString*) param1 withParam2: (NSString*) param2;` I say hit the tutorials again.

Comment: Hey @BridgetCay, I noticed you've never accepted an answer for any of your questions. If you find an answer works for you, you should click the check button under the user rating as seen here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 

People will be less responsive to answer your questions because of your lack of following this guideline.

Answer (score 4):

The function should be

```
- (void)functionWithFirstParam:(NSString *)param1 andSecondParam:(NSString *)param2;
```

`param1` and `param2` are the variables you are sending.

Thus you'll have access to the passed string as such:

```
- (void)functionWithFirstParam:(NSString *)param1 andSecondParam:(NSString *)param2 {
    NSLog(@"Param1: %@, Param2: %@",param1, param2);
}
```

and you'll call this function like this:

```
[self functionWithFirstParam:@"Hello" andSecondParam:@"World"];
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
-(void)function1:(NSString *)param1 andParam2:(NSString *)param2;
```

And then when you call it's

```
[self function1:@"333" andParam2:@"sadfas"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in Syntax of creation of method

create method such like

```
-(void)function1:(NSString *)param1 andAlsoWriteParam2:(NSString *)param2;
```

Add method in your **.m** file such like

```
-(void)function1:(NSString *)param1 andAlsoWriteParam2:(NSString *)param2 
{
  // your stuff;
}
```

And call method like

```
[self function1:@"333" andAlsoWriteParam2:@"ssdaf"]
```

Comment: Maybe bad coding syntax? should be `function1:andAlsoWriteParam2:` but I didn't -1

Comment: @JohnRiselvato - i wrote it as like because OP is new in iOS so it is better to understand :)

Comment: @JohnRiselvato - but it is typo only not important :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)function1:(NSString *)param1 secondParam:(NSString *)param2;
```

Comment: What possible value does your answer add as it stands?

Comment: I just gave an one line solution - Didn't write any junk statements explaining the wrong syntax and describing how to use the correct syntax :)

Comment: This guy is obviously just started out on programming objective-c. He is going to want to understand why his code was wrong with details, as well as how to fix it... with details.